# Auto Complete box's parameter is not setting in CDE pentaho 6.0.1

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am having problem in auto complete box component of CDE pentaho. The parameter is coming blank even though I am selecting multiple items. What am I doing wrong? How to set the parameter in auto-complete box component?